# django send email with celery task

Tags: python, django

I want to send an email to a user with order.id and "manu_date" of a specific order automatically if the deadline of the order is today. I have already configured celery with rabbitmq and it's working and I'm able to send emails. The problem is I don't know what will go into the tasks and views. So far for the task I have came up with the code below.

```
@periodic_task(run_every=datetime.timedelta(minutes=1))  
def check_for_orders():      
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc,second=00, microsecond=00)
    for order in orders:
        if order.manu_date == now:
            send_mail('Manufacturing Reminder',
                '{{Order.id}} is due {{manu_date}}',
                'dummyguy1680@gmail.com',
                ['gummy@gmail.com.com'])
            return None
```

```
class Order(models.Model):
    date = models.ForeignKey('date', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date_created', default=timezone.now(), blank=False)
    manu_date = models.DateField('Manufacturing', null=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='updated_by_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_updated = models.DateField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with celery's 'Periodic Tasks' by setting up a *crontab* to run every day and execute this task with `Celery Beat`. To set this up one method would be:

**settings.py**

```py
from celery.schedules import crontab
CELERY_BROKER_URL = <broker_address> 'for example 'amqp://myuser:mypassword@localhost:5672/myvhost'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = <your_timezone> #for example 'Europe/London'
CELERY_IMPORTS = ['<app_name>.tasks']
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
'celery_test': {

    'task': '<app_name>.tasks.check_for_orders',
    'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=0), #every day at midnight
},
}
```

Replace all `<>` with required variables for your application.

**tasks.py**

```py
from celery import shared_task
@shared_task
def check_for_orders():      
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc,second=00, microsecond=00)
    week_old = now - datetime.timedelta(week=1)
    for order in orders:
        if order.manu_date.date() == week_old.date():
            send_mail('Manufacturing Reminder',
                '{} is due {}'.format(order.id, order.manu_date),
                'dummyguy1680@gmail.com',
                ['gummy@gmail.com.com'])
            return None
```

Ensure that celery beat is running in parallel, with the worker and the application.

**Terminal to run Celery Beat**

```
celery -A EmissionsWorkbench beat -l info
```

Comment: alright so nothing goes into tasks.py and views.py?  Now i have a manu_date field in my order model , I want to send email when the manu_date is 7 days, what will be the code ? and where should i write it ?

Comment: See update for `tasks.py`. An no nothing needs to go into your views as the task is not dependant on the the users actions and can be ran periodically. When you say it's 7 days, do you mean 7 days old from now?

Comment: Sorry !  Yeah 7 days from now.

Comment: Updated answer for week old condition.